# jquery load using mysql database was working fine, then lately I've been getting an error

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have some code that works like this.

Index.php file is loaded and pulls information from a mysql database to build a dropdown jump menu.

When that menu is used, jquery is called and tries to load a specific contact from the database into an overlay window.

It was working fine and I haven't changed anything recently. I looked at the errors in chrome and they are beyond my knowledge.

Here is the error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/jsapi. Origin [my domain] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.min.js:6
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Here is my jquery (I don't show the php, because it seems to be working fine)

```
$j('#finddist').change(function(e){ e.preventDefault();


var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

var isNumeric = this.value;
if(intRegex.test(isNumeric)) {
    var loadUrl = 'http://www.accumetrics.com/en?option=com_contactenhanced&amp;view=contact&amp;id='+this.value+'&amp;tmpl=component&amp;task=preview';
    var width = 340;
} else {
    var loadUrl = 'http://accumetrics.info/accumetrics.com.v3/us-distributors?tmpl=component&amp;task=preview';
    var width = 940;
}

$j("#someDiv").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    width: width,
    overlay : {
        background: '#000',
        opacity: '0.9'  
    },
    show: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 700
    }
}); 

$j("#loading").html(ajax_load);

$j("#someDiv").load(loadUrl, null, function(responseText){  
    // alert("Response:\n" + responseText);  
    $j("#someDiv").dialog('open');
    $j("#loading").fadeOut(200);
});  

$j("#someDiv").dialog( "option", "position",[top,center]);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is barking at the call to jQuery with that error. Try in a different browser and see if you still get an error, it was likely just a bad call that is now stored in cache.

While I'm here, might as well help with your application of jQuery AJAX.

Break out your data into the appropriate strings:

```
var loadUrl,loadData,width;

if(intRegex.test(isNumeric)) {
    loadUrl = 'http://www.accumetrics.com/en';
    loadData = {option:'com_contactenhanced', view:'contact', id:this.value, tmpl:'component', task='preview'};
    width = 340;
} else {
    loadUrl = 'http://accumetrics.info/accumetrics.com.v3/us-distributors';
    loadData = {tmpl:'component', task:'preview'};
    width = 940;
}
```

Then apply it appropriately in the load.

```
$j("#someDiv").load(loadUrl, loadData, function(responseText){
```

When using any jQuery AJAX function, always separate your data from your URL into the appropriate object. Not only does it make maintaining it a lot easier, but it also allows jQuery to form the appropriate query string, rather than forcing it on you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. A coworker of mine did get this error in IE8, but this happened on her computer first in IE8, then on mine in chrome.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Accumetrics build date 2008-07-11 by RLB w/ Xyden Corp; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 21 May 2013 18:01:22 UTC


Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js


Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://cloud.crm.powerobjects.net/powerWebForm/v2/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.validate.min.js


Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://cloud.crm.powerobjects.net/powerWebForm/v2/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.accumetrics.com/templates/Accumetrics/scripts/scripts.js

Comment: yeah bro, it doesn't like the external call to jQueryUI. try using a local reference just to see if it works. if not, please provide the way you are calling jQuery and jQueryUI.

Comment: ok I'll make it local and see if that works. Should I avoid external calls altogether in the future?

Comment: no, it should work fine, i would avoid local instances of jQuery for browser caching reasons. but test to see if it works locally, and if it does, then u need to check ur server setup.

Comment: it doesn't work, but that's ok. I think I am going to go a different route. This pop up business has caused too many problems. I'm just going to go to a new page and load all, then use jquery to show/hide. thanks for the help though

Comment: ok wait! you were right, it was that call! I used the link straight from the jquery site and it works now! thanks! I still may go another route, but at least I know what to look for next time it happens!